# How to always display full size image

Tags: php, images

I'm trying to create a function that always inserts the full size image that was uploaded. My first thought was something like this:

```
function image_tag($id, $alt, $title, $align, $size) {
    $size = 'full';
    return $html;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag', 'image_tag', 10, 5);
```

Unfortunately that doesn't display anything on upload.

P.S. I do not want to have to manually set this is the **Insert Media** > **Upload Files** > **Select Files** > **Attachment Display Settings** >  **Size**.

Comment: Can i just clarify what you mean, so when someone uploads an image into the editor (no matter the size settings) when the post is viewed that image on the front end will always be full size?

Comment: @Jim-miraidev that's correct

Comment: I have a JavaScript solution,which i can post if you want?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not a PHP solution, but below is a jQuery option.

```
    var images = $('.entry-content img');

    images.each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src'),
            // removes the  img size off the src e.g -300x300.
            newsrc = src.replace(/-\d+[Xx]\d+\./,'.');         
        $(this).attr('src',newsrc);
    });
```

You would need to remove some of the classes e.g size-thumbnail